# Button created on wrong frame tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to place the buttons the arrow buttons within the blue toolbar frame on the phones class tab on the script below.

Currently the buttons appears on the left side of the main app frame, where as they should appear on the phones tab within the blue area.

The code where the issue is occurring is within the class phones app I would assume, I have posted the full code so it is easier to visualise.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.wm_title("TestApp")
        self.geometry("800x400")
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)

        self.Frame1 = cars(self.notebook)
        self.Frame2 = phones(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.Frame1, text="Cars")
        self.notebook.add(self.Frame2, text="Phones")
        self.notebook.pack(fill = 'both')


class cars(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__()

        self.labelB = tk.Label(self, text="This is the cars config page").pack()

        self.columns = ('make', 'model', 'year')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=self.columns, show='headings')
        self.tree.heading('make', text='Manufacturer')
        self.tree.heading('model', text='Make')
        self.tree.heading('year', text='Year')

        self.contacts = [("ford", "focus", 2006), ("vauxhall", "corsa", 2013),\
                      ("volkswagen", "golf", 2008), ("audi", "tt", 2018)]
        for contact in self.contacts:
            self.tree.insert('', tk.END, values=contact)

        self.tree.pack()

        moveUp = tk.Button(master=self, text=" /\ ", command=lambda: self.moveup())
        moveUp.pack()
        moveDown = tk.Button(self, text=" \/ ", command=lambda: self.movedown())
        moveDown.pack()

    def moveup(self, *args):
        self.leaves = self.tree.selection()
        for i in self.leaves:
            self.tree.move(i, self.tree.parent(i), self.tree.index(i) - 1)

    def movedown(self, *args):
        self.leaves = self.tree.selection()
        for i in reversed(self.leaves):
            self.tree.move(i, self.tree.parent(i), self.tree.index(i) + 1)


class phones(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__()

        self.labelB = tk.Label(self, text="This is the phones config page").pack()

        toolbar = tk.Frame(self, height=30, bg="navy").pack(fill = "both", expand="False")

        self.columns = ('id', 'make', 'model', 'memory', 'colour')
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=self.columns, show='headings')
        self.tree.heading('id', text='id')
        self.tree.heading('make', text='Make')
        self.tree.heading('model', text='Model')
        self.tree.heading('memory', text='Memory')
        self.tree.heading('colour', text='Colour')

        self.phones = [(1,  'apple', 'iphone 5', '32', 'red'),
            (2, 'apple', 'iphone x', '256', 'black')]
        for x in self.phones:
            self.tree.insert('', tk.END, values=x)

        self.tree.pack()
        #
        moveUp = tk.Button(toolbar, text=" /\ ", command=lambda: self.moveup())
        moveUp.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        moveDown = tk.Button(toolbar, text=" \/ ", command=lambda: self.movedown())
        moveDown.pack(side = tk.LEFT)


    def moveup(self, *args):
        self.leaves = self.tree.selection()
        for i in self.leaves:
            self.tree.move(i, self.tree.parent(i), self.tree.index(i) - 1)

    def movedown(self, *args):
        self.leaves = self.tree.selection()
        for i in reversed(self.leaves):
            self.tree.move(i, self.tree.parent(i), self.tree.index(i) + 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `toolbar` has a value of None (the result of `.pack()`, rather than the actual Frame).  Passing None as the parent of a widget makes it a child of the root window.

Answer (score 1):

As jasonharper mentioned in the comment, toolbar was returning value on None due to .pack(). So changed as follows:

```
self.toolbar = tk.Frame(self, height=30, bg="navy")
self.toolbar.pack(fill = "both", expand="False")
```